# Polybase - maximum reject threshold (0 rows) was reached while reading from an external source: 1 rows rejected out of total 1 rows processed

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

*[Question from customer]*

I have following data in a text file. Delimited by |

```
A | null , ZZ
C | D
```

When I run this query using HDInsight:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myfiledata(
col1 string,
col2 string
)
row format delimited fields terminated by '|' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://.....';
```

I get the following result as expected:

```
A     null , ZZ
C     D
```

But when I run the same query using SQL DW Polybase, it throws error:

```
Query aborted-- the maximum reject threshold (0 rows) was reached while reading from an external source: 1 rows rejected out of total 1 rows processed.
```

How do I fix this?
Here's my script in SQL DW:

```
-- Creating external data source (Azure Blob Storage) 
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE azure_storage1
WITH
(
    TYPE = HADOOP
,   LOCATION ='wasbs://....blob.core.windows.net'
,   CREDENTIAL = ASBSecret
)
;

-- Creating external file format (delimited text file)
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT text_file_format 
WITH 
(   
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT 
,   FORMAT_OPTIONS  (
                        FIELD_TERMINATOR ='|'
                    ,   USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = TRUE
                    )
)
;


-- Creating external table pointing to file stored in Azure Storage
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [Myfile] 
(
Col1    varchar(5),
Col2    varchar(5)
)
WITH 
(
    LOCATION    = '/myfile.txt'
,   DATA_SOURCE = azure_storage1
,   FILE_FORMAT = text_file_format      
)
;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We’re currently working on a way to bubble up the reason for reject to the user.

In the meantime, here's what's happening:
The default # of rows allowed to fail schema matching is 0.  This means that if at least one of the rows you’re loading in from /myfile.txt doesn’t match the schema.  In Hive, strings can accommodate an arbitrary amount of chars, but varchars cannot.  In this case it’s failing on the varchar(5) for “null , ZZ” because that is more than 5 characters.

If you’d like to change the REJECT_VALUE in the CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE call, that will let through the other row – more info can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn935021(v=sql.130).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's due to dirty record for the respective file format, for example in the case of parquet if the column contains '' (empty string) then it won't work, and will throw `Query aborted-- the maximum reject threshold`

[AZURE.NOTE] A query on an external table can fail with the error "Query aborted-- the maximum reject threshold was reached while reading from an external source". This indicates that your external data contains dirty records. A data record is considered 'dirty' if the actual data types/number of columns do not match the column definitions of the external table or if the data doesn't conform to the specified external file format. To fix this, ensure that your external table and external file format definitions are correct and your external data conform to these definitions. In case a subset of external data records is dirty, you can choose to reject these records for your queries by using the reject options in CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE DDL.